# How to use Geometry data to draw image in button

Tags: c#, wpf

The following Geometry data defined in a resource dictionary file.

```
<Geometry x:Key="EditGlyph">
    M6.7,29.3 6.7,36.7 14,36.6 31.9,18.7 24.6,11.5zM35.8,11.1l-3.6-3.6c-1-1-2.7-1-3.7,0l-3.9,3.9l7.3,7.3l3.9-3.9C36.8,13.8,36.8,12.2,35.8,11.1zM8.8,41.4 25.5,41.4 42.2,41.4
</Geometry>
```

I would like to display this drawing on a WPF Button.

How can I accomplish this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Path with that Geometry and use it as Button Content:

```
<Button>
    <Path Fill="Gold" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          Data="{StaticResource EditGlyph}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!! .... I can get the drawing inside the button but it forces the button to be a very large size.  I would like the button to be Width=18 and Height=18.  How can I scale the drawing to fit inside the button?

Comment: @chuckp, points in the geomerty have large coordiantes (36; 41) so Path grows large. set `MaxHeight="16" MaxWidth="16"` to fit it into button

Comment: Had to out the Path inside a StackPanel, and then apply a LayoutTransform/ScaleTransform to reduce the size of the Path image. Your original answer definitely got me going in the right direction. Thanks again!